# How to handle an instant response from an external API and a callback response in a single controller in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, callback, completable-future

I have a controller from where I am trying to trigger an POST external api call using headers and request body.

Sample external API URL:

```
http://sample:7070/test
```

Sample Headers:

```
Content-type: application/json
Authorization : someEncryptedData
CallBack: http://mycallback:8080/sendCallback
```

Sample Body:

```
{
"A": {
    "B": 100,
    "C": "TEST",
},
"ReceiverParty": {
    "A": 41,
    "D": "123214526"
},
"Reference": [
    {
        "Key": "A",
        "Value": "B"
    }
]
}
```

Now this api will send an instant response when it is triggered. Also it will send another response to the callback url(POST) provided in the header.

**I want to get the both response in one controller. What's the approach to get it? Kindly refer to any blog of topic for better understanding.**

My sample code:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/main")
public class MainController {

@Autowired
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

@PostMapping("/call-api")
public ResponseEntity<String> callApi() {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    // Create the request body
    SamplePlayload requestPayload = createRequestPayload();

    HttpEntity<SamplePlayload> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(requestPayload, headers);

    ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(
            "http://sample:7070/test",
            HttpMethod.POST,
            requestEntity,
            String.class
    );

    String initialResponse = responseEntity.getBody();
    System.out.println("Received initial response: " + initialResponse);

    String callbackUrl = "http://mycallback:8080/sendCallback"; 

    CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> restTemplate.postForObject(callbackUrl, 
    requestPayload, String.class))
            .thenAccept(callbackResponse -> {
                System.out.println("Received callback response: " + 
    callbackResponse);
                // Perform further actions as needed
            });

    return responseEntity;
}

private SamplePlayload createRequestPayload() {
    //make the request body
}
```

Callback Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/sendCallback")
public class CallbackController {

@PostMapping
public void handleCallback(@RequestBody CallbackResponse callbackResponse) {
    // Process the callback response
    System.out.println("Received callback response: " + callbackResponse);
    // Perform further actions as needed
    }
}
```

Sample instant Response:

```
{
"Header": {
//some elements
},
"Body": {
//Some elements
}
}
```

Sample callback Response:

```
{
"Header": {
//some elements
},
"Body": {
//Some elements
}
}
```

Comment: If you want the response from the call to `restTemplate.postForObject` to be returned to the method that called it, then either don't execute this asynchronously, or block until you get a response.  You have no other options unless you want to return a CompletableFuture from your controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it as a service and give a resttemplate call to another microservice like and get the response

Comment: can you give me any example? Or any blog or article refer to this? Thanks

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just modify the callback url path?

Move the `handleCallback` method to `MainController` and align the modified path for the header as well.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/main")
public class MainController {
 
   ...
    
    @PostMapping("/sendCallback")
    public void handleCallback(@RequestBody CallbackResponse callbackResponse) {
        // Process the callback response
        System.out.println("Received callback response: " + callbackResponse);
        // Perform further actions as needed
    }
}
```

New header:

```
Content-type: application/json
Authorization : someEncryptedData
CallBack: http://mycallback:8080/main/sendCallback
```

Comment: I have similar kind of two api call operation after getting the data from callback. From the frontend they will just hit the /call-api endpoint. What will I return from this method? And do I need to perform remaining api calls and operations on handle callback method? Thanks